# How to run checkerframework in IntelliJ?

Tags: checker-framework

I have a multi subproject using gradle with the kotlin DSL. I want to use the checkerframework to apply the NullnessChecker.

My gradle config:

```
plugins {
    id("org.checkerframework") version "0.6.35"
}

subprojects {
    if (file("src/main/java").isDirectory) {
        apply(plugin = "org.checkerframework")
        checkerFramework {
            checkers = listOf("org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker")
        }
    }
...
}
```

This works if I run my build by:

1. Running from the commandline
2. Running the Build>>Rebuild Module from within IntelliJ

Which results in an error like:

```
MyClass.java:29: error: [argument] incompatible argument for parameter variable1 of MyClass.allNull.
        new MyClass().allNull(null);
                              ^
```

Ideally I want IntelliJ to alert me on this as well when/as I change code. Either with the error like above or with squiggly lines.

I have found 2 ways to do this:

1. With IntelliJ inspections by switching these 2 checkboxes on: [image: Nullability and data flow problems inspection] But this means that there are 2 different ways to do null checks and a possibility that what is done by IntelliJ and the checker framework not to be in sync.
2. By automatically enable the this checkbox[image: Build project automatically] This works as I make changes but it displays the errors in the Auto-build tab [image: Auto-build tab] The Auto-build tab does not get display automatically if there are any errors and does not allert me otherwise.

The checkerframework [documentation](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#intellij) says in section 37.10 'If your project uses a build tool (Ant, Gradle, Maven, etc.), do not use the instructions in this section'.

Is there no other way to run the NullnessChecker in IntelliJ and get squiggly lines?